# Effeciently replacing a variable number of NA values based on logical vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I am attempting to replace NA values in my data frame based on the logical return of one of the columns in the data frame.

```
#Creating random example data frame
a <- rbinom(1000,1,.5)
b <- rbinom(1000,1,.75)
c <- rbinom(1000,1,.25)
d <- rbinom(1000,1,.5)
e <- rbinom(1000,1,.5) # Will be the logical column
df <- cbind(a,b,c,d)

for(i in 1:1000){
  if(sum(df[i,1:4]) >2){
    df[i,1:4] <- NA
  }
}
# randomly replacing some of the NA to represent the observation data
df[sample(1:length(df), 100, replace=F)] <- 1

df <- cbind(df, e)
```

I am attempting to fill in the `NA`s with 0 when `e == 1` while still retaining the random 1s I placed in the the other 4 columns (especially those where the rest of the values are NA).
I've tried creating loops like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[,'e']==1){
    df[i,is.na(df[i,1:4])] <- 0 
  }
}
```

however that clears both my logical column and my observation data.

The data frame that I want to apply this to is large (2.8 million rows X 23 col) containing metadata and observation data so something that takes speed into account would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df)
setDT(df1)
for(j in 1:4){
 set(df1, i = which(df1[['e']]==1 & is.na(df1[[j]])), j = j, value = 0)
}
```

It would be more efficient as we are using `set`.  Based on the help page of `set` (`?set`) overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided by calling it.

---

As @thelatemail mentioned a compact `base R` option would be

```
df[,1:4][df[,"e"]==1 & is.na(df[,1:4])] <- 0
```

If the matrix is very big, the logical matrix would be big as well and that could potentially create memory-related issues.

Comment: Probably not memory efficient on huge data - so I'll just throw it here - `df[,1:4][df[,"e"]==1 & is.na(df[,1:4])] <- 0` should work in base R.

Comment: @akrun Works great (and fast) thanks! There is one strange thing though. On columns that have no obs in them, rows satisfying `e == 1` return `FALSE` rather than filling with `0`. It's easy enough to solve but I'm just curious if you know why that happens?

Comment: @Reed Did you meant that it is all `NA` column ?  Can you check the class of that column?

Comment: @Reed I tried by assinging the third column to NA i.e all NA values `df[,3] <- NA` and then tried the code.  It does work for me. `head(df1)#
   a b  c d e
1: 0 1  0 0 1
2: 0 0 NA 0 0
3: 0 0 NA 1 0`  Note that the NA values that are not corresponding to e==1 will remain NA as the condition was like that.

Comment: @Reed If your problem is not that, please do post as a new question.